# Font size in Flatpak OBS

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, kde-plasma-5, flatpak

F37, KDE Plasma, Xorg

When I install OBS from rpmfusion it respects my font settings in KDE. But when it is installed from Flatpak the fonts are small. How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using a Flatseal Environment Variable

1. Install Flatseal:

```bash
$ sudo flatpak install flathub com.github.tchx84.Flatseal
```

2. Launch Flatseal and select the troublesome Flatpak application.
3. Under the **Environment — Variables** section, add the line:
   `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.25`